# How to auto-query the direction from live location to a certain location on Google Maps api?

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, location, user-experience, direction

It's some weird, and I am not sure that I've properly summarized the question on title. But that is what I am trying to do:

- Pin a certain location on Google Maps. (Destination) **[DONE]**
- Identify the user's live location. **[DONE]**
- Take the user's live location as starting point **[WHAT I'M ASKING]**
- Automatically show Google Maps' directions and transpotation alternatives.

I just want to clearify my question by this shortlist. I wonder if there is a way to do it on my client's website. As a golden point, I would not prefer to use a 3rd party solution because of security matters.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that you are using **Wordpress**, if you are not able to find any plugin that will solve your problem, my advise is to do a little customization.

Getting the user's live (current) position is pretty simple in **[Google Maps Javasript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)**. All you need to use in your application is **[HTML5 Geolocation feature](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)** along with our API. Once coordinates acquired through the getCurrentPosition method:

```
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}
```

you can now use it to add the **[Google Map Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)**. But please keep in mind of the following when you wish to use the HTML 5 Geolocation feature:

- Check if Geolocation is supported
- If supported, run the getCurrentPosition() method. If not, display a message to the user
- If the getCurrentPosition() method is successful, it returns a coordinates object to the function specified in the parameter (showPosition)
- The showPosition() function outputs the Latitude and Longitude

Below is simple demonstration using HTML5 geolocation + Directions Service

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 500px;
        width: 100%;  
      }
      #mapContainer {
        width:700px;
        float:left;
        overflow:hidden;
        display: block;    
      }  
      #destinationHolder {
        width: 300px;
        float: left;
        padding: 10px; 
      }  
      #destinationHolder h3 {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, san-serif;  
      }  
      #destinationHolder input {
        width:200px;
        border:solid 1px #CCC;
        padding: 0 5px;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 10px 0 0;  
        line-height:30px;
      }  
      #destinationHolder button {
        line-height: 30px;
        border:none;
        background-color:#444;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:14px;  
        cursor:pointer;
      }  
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="mapContainer">
           <div id="map"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="destinationHolder">
        <input type="text" id="destination_input" value="Please put destination" onClick="this.select();" />
        <button id="submit">Go!</button> 
      </div>
    <script>
      var map, infoWindow;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 12
        });
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();        
        directionsRenderer.setMap(map);  

        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            var originMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: pos,
                map: map,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                title: 'My current position!'
            });    
            map.setCenter(pos);
            document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function(){
                console.log('test');
                calculateAndDisplayRoute(pos,directionsService,directionsRenderer)
            });  
          }, function() {
            console.log('current position issue');
          });
        } else {
          console.log('Browser does not support Geolocation!');
        }
      }
        
      function calculateAndDisplayRoute(origin, directionsService, directionsRenderer) {
        directionsService.route(
            {
              origin: origin,
              destination: {query: document.getElementById('destination_input').value},
              travelMode: 'DRIVING',
              provideRouteAlternatives: true
            },
            function(response, status) {
              if (status === 'OK') {
                directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
                  console.log(response);
              } else {
                window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
              }
            });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Regarding this demo, I've used an input box for the destination as I do not know the exact value of this. You can just change the value of this: **destination: {query: document.getElementById('destination_input').value}** to whatever you like (e.g. destination: 'San Francisco, USA').

By setting the Directions Service's property **provideRouteAlternatives** to **true** will return the alternative routes to your destination. Of course you'll have to modify the sample code that I've given to you to achieve this. You can refer to this **jsbinhttps://jsbin.com/salahiz/edit?js,output** as reference on how to plot the alternate routes.

Hope this information find you helpful and good luck on your project!